# This function always returns nonetype(). Python

Tags: python, algorithm, tuples

```
(3, 2)
(2, 1)
(1, 8)
(8, 6)
(8, 7)
(7, 4)
(4, 5)
```

This is the list of tuples. The function accepts arguments source and destination. It should return how many steps it takes to go from one number to another in the list. Suppose source is 2 and dest is 8, the function should return 2 steps. As first step is from 2 to 1, then the next step is from 1 to 8.

```
roads=[]                         #the list of tuples
for i in range(n-1):
    j,o=input("").split()
    roads.append((int(j),int(o)))

def dist(self, s, d):
    count,z,cn=0,0,0
    if s==d:                    #if the source and dest are the same
        return int(0)
    while z<len(roads):         #iterating over each tuple
        if s in roads[z]:
            if s==roads[z][0]:               
                for p in range(len(roads)):   #iterating again to check other if other member appears elsewhere in the list
                    if roads[z][1] in roads[p]:
                        cn+=1
                if cn>1:               #checking if the other member is a dead end  
                    s=roads[z][1]
                    count+=1           #increasing count for each step
                cn=0
            elif s== roads[z][1]:      #same thing again 
                for j in range(len(roads)):      
                    if roads[z][0] in roads[j]:
                        cn+=1
                if cn>1:
                    s=roads[z][0]
                    count+=1
                cn=0
        else:
            pass
        z+=1         #wrapping around if the list reaches the end
        if s==d:
            break    #if source reaches dest, breaking out
        if z==len(roads):
            z=0

    return count
```

But the function is always returning nonetype() instead of an int. I know the code looks messy. Can you help?

**Code Description** :First the tuples are stored in a list of tuples called roads. Then in the function dist, I iterate over each tuple to see if the source `s` is present inside. If I find it, I check if the other member of the tuple leads to a dead end. If not then I proceed and make that other member the source `s` and continue with the iteration, wrapping around when I reach the end of the list. Until i reach the destination `d`, then i break and return the count.

Comment: What do you mean by **not working**? Which case? See [mcve].

Comment: Where do you call dist?

Comment: This is part of a program where dist is called several times, to evaluate the steps it takes to go from a to b in the list. The tuple list i gave is just an example of what dist gets to work with.

Comment: are you trying to say that it always returns 0? it does not appear possible for this function to ever return `None`

Comment: No, it returns nonetype(). Doesn't return either 0 or the integer:count. Is there an infinite loop or something which i can't find?

Comment: Maybe you do not call the function you think you do. Please post a MCVE, i.e. that demonstrates how you call the function, that allows us to reproduce the error. Cut out all the code irrelevant to the problem, i.e., remove as much business logic as possible while still preserving the error. Does it still fail, when you remove the loop?

Comment: Your question is astonishingly similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42657008/1025391 - Please don't post the same question over and over (even with different user accounts).

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I'll try that. I didn't do that till now, because the whole code is so big, but I'll try if I can cut out stuff and still preserve the error. And yeah I had posted it once before yesterday, forgot to delete it as it was a poorly described question and got downvotes. Was my first question here. So had to create a new acc so i could ask this again.

Comment: I highly recommend using a better algorithm here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search. You can use `Queue` from the `queue` package to help you with that.

Comment: Thanks! That was really helpful. I just started using python 3-4 days ago and hadn't really started googling for packages and modules...This current algorithm is just too messy